# CodeIgniter: Displaying data from two tables in a view - use one loop?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, fetch

I'd like some help please. 
I have these two database tables, with relationship 1-n (one album has many images):

```
  albums            images
----------       -------------
album_id            img_id
title               album_id
description         img_file
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to **show all the albums with their images in my view**, something like [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/free-website-template/), see the 2nd screenshot (portfolio).

This is what I have in my Controller:

```
// fetch all album data 
$albums = $this->album_model->get();

// fetch images for each album
foreach ($albums as $album ) {
 $images = $this->albumimage_model->get_by('album_id', $album->album_id);
}

$data = array(
 'albums'  =>  $albums, 
 'images'  =>  $images, 
);
$this->load->view('album_listing', $data);
```

If i loop through the album data in my view, I get this:

```
<?php foreach($albums as $album): ?>
<div class="album">
<p><?php echo $album->title; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $album->description; ?></p>
<div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So far so good, but now here comes the headache:
**I want to display the images that belong to each album**, so basicle something like this:

```
<?php foreach($albums as $album): ?>
<div class="album">
    <p><?php echo $album->title; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $album->description; ?></p>

    // show all images of the album
    <div class="images"><img src="uploads/<php? echo $album->title;  ?>.'/'.<php? echo $image->image_file;  ?> " /></div>

<div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can I accomplish that, according to the CodeIgniter practices???

Some additional info: 
1. I have also enable the CodeIgntier's Profiler and I've noticed that the running queries are incremented like this. Whouldn't this increase the memmory in case I have many albums (50 - 100 albums with images)???

1. I also tried to do this using just one query with JOIN, something like this:

   $albums = $this->db->select('albums.*')
     ->select('images.img_id, images.img_file')
     ->join('images', 'images.album_id = albums.album_id')
     ->order_by('albums.album_id')
     ->get('albums')
     ->result_array();

The problem with this is when I loop through the data (lets say I have two albums in my database), I get the data twice on my page, like :

```
album1 - images of album 1
album1 - images of album 1
album2 - images of album 2
album2 - images of album 2
```

Comment: Are you using jamierumbelow's base model?

Comment: No I use this http://codeigniter.tv/videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = $this->db->get('albums');
$albums = $query->result_array();

$query = $this->db->get('images');
$images =$query->result_array();

foreach ($albums as $album)
{

    foreach ($images as $image)
    { 
        if($image['album_id'] == $album['album_id']){
            $data[$album['album_id']]['images'] = $image['album_id'];
        }
    }
}

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: I've tested this but it returns the album data many times. See waht I've writen in my post above please

Comment: I have edited please check. and use ->get() instead of ->get('albums')

Comment: When you loop through this query, will alway return many times the same album data. Its the same with what I've done.

Comment: can I have a look on you table data

Comment: I have posted my table structure on the post. please review

Comment: yes I can see, actually I'm asking for the data of the table.

Comment: Is this really necessary? I don't see the point ... you can use any thing you want as long as it follows the structure

Comment: actually I interested because seems like there might be multiple entries. I have run same query in my local machine and got fine everything as expected.

Comment: album 1:
1, firstalbum, this is the first album |

album 2:
2, secondalbum, this is the second album |

images:
1, 1, butterflies.jpg |
2, 1, snowboard.jpg |
3, 2, fast_car.jpg |

Comment: ->join('images', 'images.album_id = albums.album_id', 'LEFT') 

kindly try this one

Comment: I tested it in phpmyadmin. Here are the returned rows (in this order album_id, title, description, image_file):
row 1: 1, firstalbum, this is the first album, butterflies.jpg |
row 2: 1, firstalbum, this is the first album, snowboard.jpg |
row 3: 2, secondalbum, this is the second album, fast_car.jpg|
row 4: 2, secondalbum, this is the second album, sailing.jpg

Comment: its seems okay. butterflies.jpg, snowboard.jpg, fast_car.jpg, sailing.jpg. four different entries of images so that's why your getting four column

Comment: yes, but when I loop through the data in the view, I get these 4 rows. What I actually want is to have all album data shown once only (so I don't get many times title and description) and next to them show all images.

Comment: sounds like, 
album 1 images a, b
album 2 images c,d

Comment: you need to manipulate this into model and stored in an array and then send the stored array to view.

`array(
   'album 1' => array('image1', 'image2')
   'album 2' => array('image 3', 'image4')
);`

Comment: I 'm not sure what  exactly you mean.. my queries are already in models and results are returned as arrays. Could you be more specific or give a code example???

Comment: I tested it, but not working correct. It lists all album titles and descriptions first, and then all images together. Each album contain images with the same album id as you said

Comment: I did some changes and worked! I marked it as correct, however if there's a better solution to this, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of duplicate entries try to use `SELECT DISTINCT` in your query, which serves for similar purposes.
Also, I don't really understand what do you mean by:

> running queries are incremented like this

Comment: the SELECT DISTINCT where should I test it? in the case of the JOIN query or with the 2 queries??

Comment: It's when you get your data twice, with `JOIN`.

Comment: return a mysql error: Column 'album_id' in order clause is ambiguous

Comment: It means that you are trying to order by a column name that is used in more than one table; but in your statement it's ok: `order_by('albums.album_id')`. You should use it like `$this->db->distinct()`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do Something Like Following

Controller -

```
// fetch all album data <br>
$data['albums']= $this->album_model->get_albums();
// fetch all images<br>
$data['images']=  = $this->album_model->get_images();
$this->load->view('album_listing', $data);<br>
```

View (album_listing.php)

```
foreach ($albums as $album)
{

    foreach ($images as $image)
    { 
        if($image->album_id == $album->album_id)
        echo "Album - ".$album->album_id.", Title".$album->title.", Description".$album->description." Image ID - ".$image->img_id."Img File - ".$image->img_file;
    }
}
```

---

In Alternate
In your Model

```
    public function get_images(){
    { 
       $sql ="select a.album_id, a.description, i.img_id, i.img_file from album a, image i where a.album_id = i.album_id"
       $query = $this->db->query($sql);
       $data   =   array();
       foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
       }
    return $data;
    }
```

Controller

```
 $data['albums_img']= $this->album_model->get_images();
 $this->load->view('album_listing', $data);
```

View

```
 foreach ($albums_img as $album)
 { 

    echo "Album - ".$album->album_id.", Title".$album->title.", Description".$album->description." Image ID - ".$album->img_id."Img File - ".$album->img_file;
 }
```

Hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: this will increase time and space complexity. because multiple query will run where as you can do it by single query :)

Comment: I'm trying to follow CI's practices so album_model matches the albums table, and image_model matches the images table